# Why does $z^3=0$ have 3 complex roots and not simply just $0$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

By the fundamental theorem of algebra, it should be that $z^3=0$ has 3 solutions. However, when I attempt to calculate the roots,

$$z^3=0\iff (re^{i\theta})^3=0e^{i\theta_1}$$ so $3i\theta =i\theta_1$ which implies that $\theta=\frac{\theta_1+2\pi ik}{3}$ where $k\in\{0,1,2\}$ and $r=0$. However, since the radius is zero, wouldn't all three roots simply be zero meaning it only has a single root which is $0+0bi$?

Comment: $0$ is the only solution.

Comment: @Surb Why doesn't this contradict the fundamental theorem of algebra?

Comment: It doesn't contradict the fundamental theorem of algebra.  There is one root of multiplicity 3.  That is fine.

Comment: @DougM I found my confusion. the fundamental theorem of algebra can be stated as follows: every non-zero, single-variable, degree n polynomial with complex coefficients has counted with multiplicity, exactly n complex roots. However, this polynomial has one root with multiplicity 3 not three roots.

Comment: The phrase "the polynomial has $n$ roots, counted with multiplicity" means "the sum of the multiplicities of the roots of the polynomial equals $n$".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of algebra states that every polynomial of degree $n$ can be written as $c(z-z_1)(z-z_2)...(z-z_n)$ where $z_1, z_2,...,z_n$ are not necessary distinct. If the root $z_i$ appears exactly $k$ times in this decomposition then we say this root has multiplicity $k$. **So if we count such a root $k$ times** then the polynomial has exactly $n$ solutions.

For example, the polynomial $p(z)=z^3$ has just one root, and the multiplicity of this root is $3$.

Comment: $$z^3=(z-0)(z-0)(z-0).$$